# Closed form of a nonlinear recurrence sequence.

Tags: computer-science, algorithms, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

The master theorem seems to fail on nonlinear recursive functions. Is there a standard tool for finding the closed forms of recursive functions of this form?

The question comes from trying to find the closed form of the following recursive function:
$f_i(X) = (f_{i-1}(X)^2 + f_{i-1}(X))/2$
Where:
$f_0(X) = X$

I would be willing to part with recurrence relations for this function, but I would be much more delighted to learn a general method or trick which makes finding closed forms of functions like this simple.

Comment: I think you may want to retitle this something like "Closed form for a nonlinear recurrence sequence?"

Comment: Generally speaking, nonlinear recurrences almost never have closed forms.

Comment: I changed the title as suggested.

Comment: Qiaochu is right. Whatever general results there are for nonlinear recurrences, they should be in here: 

http://books.google.com/books?id=LmfonVHe7MMC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_navlinks_s#v=onepage&q=&f=false

I own this book myself, but have only studied the parts of it relevant to linear recurrences, so I can't direct you to anything specific.

Comment: Seems like I'm out of luck. I just compared the function in question with logistic maps (the similarity is striking). No wonder I was butting my head against a wall.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9660/closed-forms-for-monotonic-polynomial-recurrences

Comment: In fact, to my knowledge the only quadratic recurrence which has anything like a closed form is (anything that reduces to) x_{n+1} = 2x_n^2 - 1 because of the cosine double-angle formula.

Comment: [Or x_{n+1}=cx_n^2, he said, pedantically]

Comment: Do you actually mean they never have closed forms (i.e. can it be proved that a "closed form" (defined in some concrete manner) doesn't exist in some cases?), or that we're currently unable to find them (i.e. it is possible that someone in the future could find one)?

Answer (score 1):

As has already been explained, there is no hope in general of finding explicit solutions to nonlinear recurrences. However, for your example, it is possible to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(X)$ for all real $X$.

The function $g(x)=(x^2+x)/2$ has two fixed points: $x=0$ (atractor) and $x=1$ (repulsor). Its respective stable sets are $(-2,1)$ and $\{-2,1\}$; $(-\infty,-2)\cup(1,+\infty)$ is the stable set of $+\infty$. Thus,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(X)=\left\{\matrix{0, & X\in(-2,1)\cr 1, & X\in\{-2,1\}\cr +\infty, & X\in(-\infty,-2)\cup(1,+\infty)}\right.$$